# bootstrap grid small medium size not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design, grid

Good afternoon,
I work on responsive web and I need to do 1 col on small displays and 2 on bigger. I used `col-12` and `col-lg-6` but when I needed change it but combination col-12 and `col-md-6` didnt work.

Strange thing is that it works on jsfiddle but not on my web.

Here is code on my web and jsfiddle link.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous" />
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <style>
            #blue {
                background:blue;
            }
            #red{
                background: red;
            }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>



        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">...</div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">...</div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">...</div>

                <!-- Add the extra clearfix for only the required viewport -->
                <div class="clearfix visible-md visible-lg"></div>

                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">...</div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">...</div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">...</div>
            </div>


            <div class="row">
                <div id="blue" class="col-12 col-md-6">
                    class="col-12 col-md-6"
                </div>
                <div id="red" class="col-12 col-md-6 ">
                    class="col-12 col-md-6"
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div id="blue" class="col-12 col-lg-6">
                    class="col-12 col-lg-6"
                </div>
                <div id="red" class="col-12 col-lg-6 ">
                    class="col-12 col-lg-6"
                </div>
            </div>




        </div>



    </body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5yjtn1u5/

Comment: There are no class `col-12`. you need to add `col-md-12` (i.e. `md, lg, etc)

Comment: it's working.. what the issue? https://jsfiddle.net/5yjtn1u5/1/

Comment: @AjayMakwana `bootstrap` has `col-12` class bro. It is `Bootstrap 4` here's the link https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/

Comment: @nethkennnnn Thanks, bro. I didn't know that.

Comment: The problem is that I have defined xs, sm, md, lg and with blue, red combination I have defined col-12, col-md-6 and secondly col-12, col-lg-6. When I try to roll up/down with "CONTROL" (zooming) it works "properly" but when I open developer tools in browser and try mobile devices e.g. iPad, Galaxy, iPhone it doesnt work. Only what is working is combination of 2 divs with classes col-12 and col-lg-6 anything else doesnt change responsively.

Answer (score 0):

The discrepancy between JSFiddle and running on a browser appears to be the device size. The JSFiddle example is running as a Medium device, while your web example is probably big enough to be Large device like mine was. Your code failed because on a Large device, "col-12" will be selected instead of "col-md-6", if that was your problem.